# Fill screen with background colour and set text size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two problems.

1. The background colour #eee doesn't extend to the bottom of the screen. I've tried amending plenty of containers but it just won't budge. I've tried extending the HTML to 100% height. Nothing.
2. The glyph icons won't reach 100px in size, even though I'm referencing the correct class.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

The full HTML, with the relevant parts from the CSS.

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.call-to-action {
 text-align: center;
  color: #9D343D;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
}
.call-to-action p {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}
.glyphicon-large {
 font-size: 100px;
  color: #9D343D;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
}

#wrapper {
  background: #eee;
}

#body {
  background: #eee;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  background: #eee;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Swindon Mela Home Page</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">

          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
              </div>

              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </nav>

                      <div class="jumbotron container-fluid">
                        <h1>Swindon Mela</h1>
                        <p>Swindon Mela is a one day event to celebrate Indian culture in Swindon.</p>
                        <p>
                          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="container">
                        <section class="call-to-action">
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                         <h3>Vibrant community</h3>
                         <p>Swindon Mela hosts a vibrant community.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous glpyhicon-large" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                         <h3>Outdoors</h3>
                         <p>Swindon Mela is held outdoors with plenty of community offerings for the whole family.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gbp glpyhicon-large" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                         <h3>Donate</h3>
                         <p>If you would like to become an official sponsor, please get in touch through our donation page!</p>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                      </section>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="filler" class="fill">
          <div class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- This is filler -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#wrapper {
  background: #eee;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

EDIT:

```
<html>
    <body>

      <div class='your_container'>

        <div class='your_second_container'>

        </div>

      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

When You set `height:100%` for html and body, then You can set `min-height:100%` for first div ( here `your_container` ) and **it will fill at least 100% of body height**. Of course You can set `min-height:100%;` for body when html have `height:100%;`

EDIT ICONS:

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-console my_icon'></span>

CSS:

  .my_icon{
    font-size:100px;
  }
```

Does it work?

**PS. You got typo in html - glpyhicon-large , but You use .glyphicon-large in CSS ;-)**

Comment: Excellent! I got rid of the first wrapper actually since it wasn't doing anything, and added this to page-content-wrapper instead. Could you please explain what the # in CSS does and why this works?

Comment: it works because You set height:100% for body and html - which means that body and html should have 100% height of document, but when it's empty or not fully filled it will cover only filled space. When You set min-height:100% for first element ( and html and body set to height:100% ) then Your first div will cover AT LEAST 100% of document height.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your contents and click ' inspect element', then you would know where your background actually belongs to.

To set a global background, you would likely need to set the background under 'body' tag

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I just tried this and it did nothing.

    body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background: #eee;
    }

Comment: Inspect your element, and see where it actually belongs to, that's how a newbie truly become a developer

Comment: I did, and yeah it looks like it's the body... but I've tried background and background-color in the CSS for the body tag and nothing's changed. I'm still a little lost.

Comment: To me, it looks like the filler object is taking place. But you need to start learning how to debug your own code sometiem

Comment: Ah yes - the filler object was my attempt at fixing the issue. If I get rid of it, problem still exists.